Core Image Metal kernel compile flag makes SwiftUI can not find Metal shader
I use the Core Image Metal kernel, to make it work, it's needed to add -fcikernel to the Other Metal Complie Flags and Other Metal Link Flags in build settings.
Here is the article talking about this.
But after adding the flag
The metal shader here can not be loaded.
@available(iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, watchOS 10.0, tvOS 17.0, visionOS 1.0, *)
internal struct GlurModifier: ViewModifier {
    public var radius: CGFloat
    public var offset: CGFloat
    public var interpolation: CGFloat
    public var direction: BlurDirection
    
    @Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale
    
    let library = ShaderLibrary.default 
    
    var blurX: Shader {
        var shader = library.blurX(.float(radius),
                                   .float(offset),
                                   .float(interpolation),
                                   .float(Float(direction.rawValue)),
                                   .float(displayScale))
        shader.dithersColor = true
        return shader
    }

NSBundle....simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MetalTools.framework/ principal class is nil because all fallbacks have failed

You have multiple options for avoiding the manual compilation:
You could give the Metal files that contain the CI kernels a different file extensions, e.g., .ci.metal, and then add different build rules that apply to those files. This is outlined in the WWDC video that is also linked to in the article. The video only mentions the old extern "C" kernel format, but by adapting the compiler flags, it should also work with the new [[stitchable]] format.
Alternatively, you could put all your CI kernel .metal files into a different target in Xcode, and then change the Metal flags only for that target. The kernels will be built into a different bundle, and you can load them from there. (This naturally also works when putting the SwiftUI shaders into a different bundle instead.)

Found a workaround, it seems that all the metal files in the target will be built into a normal .metallib library. But adding the -fcikernel makes it build for CIKernel. I end up building one of the .metallib using command line.
xcrun -sdk iphoneos metal -c -mios-version-min=15.0 blur.metal -o blur.air 
xcrun -sdk iphoneos metallib blur.air -o blur.metallib 
Then add the output file to the target.
let library = ShaderLibrary(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "blur", withExtension: "metallib")!)

The drawback is you have to manually build it when you update the metal file and it can not work on simulator. Guess the better way to do it is separate two different metal source file into frameworks?
